# need to implement virtual wallet in an iOS app (For Austria region), where the user can pay via credits to the seller and i take my cut in real time

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment-processing, wallet

I need to implement virtual wallet in an iOS app (For Austria region), where the user can pay via credits to the seller and I take my cut in real time. For example, if user has to pay $ 10 to the seller, then I'd get $ 2 in my account and 8 to seller's. Is there any service that I can leverage for this workflow? or if apple in-App is the answer?

I'd be fine even if transaction happens in real currency (can do away virtual credits etc), the priority is I get my cut to be credited in real time as well before seller gets the fee; please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically speaking, this sort of "immediacy" can produce *accounting* problems. In the real world of business, transactions *can* be made in error, and the customer *can* demand (and, *get* ...) his money back.

Therefore, "settlements" are normally paid sometime after-the-fact, although the amount-*payable* is calculated immediately.

For example, consider what happens when you buy a meal at a restaurant with your credit card. The transaction is *approved* in real time, but then it is placed into a "batch" that is "settled" by the restaurant, probably at the end of the business day. The money might not arrive in the restaurant's bank account for many days thereafter. *(Especially(!) in the case of American Express!)*

Although the company immediately knows what amounts are *due,* it does not have the money *yet.*

Likewise, the restaurant buys its food and other materials "on credit," issuing a Purchase Order which is effectively a promissory note.

When the customer tenders a 10-credit transaction, 2 credits become *payable* to you, and the remaining 8 are *payable* to the vendor. But, neither transfer has actually happened *yet.* You might not actually get your money/credits until after some period of time has passed, *e.g.* the initial "money-back guarantee" or "buyer's remorse" period. The accountants book this revenue as "A/P," and *periodically* they "cut a check," accompanied by a statement which details which A/P entries have been settled thereby. Once you receive the check you are legally entitled to cash it, and if the issuing company finds that it has made a mistake (or the customer takes his sweet time before demanding ... and, getting ... his money back), the issuing company takes the loss. (And maybe also writes the vendor a not-so polite letter.)